# How solving MINLP with Pyomo using MindtPy?

Tags: pyomo

If someone has the solution to this error.
I want to solve MINLP problem using pyomo package with MindtPy, but I didn't find the right solver.
When I run my code with this solver:

```
opt=SolverFactory('mindtpy').solve(model,strategy='OA',mip_solver='cplex',nlp_solver='ipopt',add_regularization='level_L1')
```

the parameters of the solver:

Starting MindtPy version 0.1.0 using OA algorithm
iteration_limit: 50
stalling_limit: 15
time_limit: 2000
strategy: OA
add_regularization: hess_only_lag
call_after_main_solve: <pyomo.contrib.gdpopt.util._DoNothing object at 0x0000019EFF362100>
call_after_subproblem_solve: <pyomo.contrib.gdpopt.util._DoNothing object at 0x0000019EFF362130>
call_after_subproblem_feasible: <pyomo.contrib.gdpopt.util._DoNothing object at 0x0000019EFF362160>
tee: false
logger: <Logger pyomo.contrib.mindtpy (INFO)>
logging_level: 20
integer_to_binary: false
add_no_good_cuts: false
use_tabu_list: false
single_tree: false
solution_pool: false
num_solution_iteration: 5
cycling_check: true
feasibility_norm: L_infinity
differentiate_mode: reverse_symbolic
use_mcpp: false
calculate_dual_at_solution: true
use_fbbt: false
use_dual_bound: true
partition_obj_nonlinear_terms: true
quadratic_strategy: 0
move_objective: true
add_cuts_at_incumbent: false
heuristic_nonconvex: false
init_strategy: rNLP
level_coef: 0.5
solution_limit: 10
reduce_level_coef: false
use_bb_tree_incumbent: false
sqp_lag_scaling_coef: fixed
fp_cutoffdecr: 0.1
fp_iteration_limit: 20
fp_projcuts: true
fp_transfercuts: true
fp_projzerotol: 0.0001
fp_mipgap: 0.01
fp_discrete_only: true
fp_main_norm: L1
fp_norm_constraint: true
fp_norm_constraint_coef: 1.0
add_slack: false
max_slack: 1000.0
OA_penalty_factor: 1000.0
equality_relaxation: false
linearize_inactive: false
nlp_solver: ipopt
nlp_solver_args:
mip_solver: cplex
mip_solver_args:
mip_solver_mipgap: 0.1
threads: 0
regularization_mip_threads: 1
solver_tee: false
mip_solver_tee: false
nlp_solver_tee: false
mip_regularization_solver: cplex
absolute_bound_tolerance: 0.0001
relative_bound_tolerance: 0.001
small_dual_tolerance: 1.0e-08
integer_tolerance: 1.0e-05
constraint_tolerance: 1.0e-06
variable_tolerance: 1.0e-08
zero_tolerance: 1.0e-08
obj_bound: 1000000000000000.0
continuous_var_bound: 10000000000.0
integer_var_bound: 1000000000.0
initial_bound_coef: 0.1

---

```
           Mixed-Integer Nonlinear Decomposition Toolbox in Pyomo (MindtPy)
```

---

For more information, please visit
https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contributed_packages/mindtpy.html
If you use this software, please cite the following:
Bernal, David E., et al. Mixed-integer nonlinear decomposition toolbox for Pyomo (MindtPy).
Computer Aided Chemical Engineering. Vol. 44. Elsevier, 2018. 895-900.

Original model has 896 constraints (0 nonlinear) and 0 disjunctions, with 864 variables, of which 864 are binary, 0 are integer, and 0 are continuous.
rNLP is the initial strategy being used.

===============================================================================================
Iteration | Subproblem Type | Objective Value | Primal Bound |   Dual Bound |   Gap   | Time(s)

Moving objective to constraint set.
-       Relaxed NLP        5.4095e+06            inf     5.4095e+06      nan%    241.72
I find this error:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10232\2828786147.py in <module>
      1 Qc_added=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
      2 CB=[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
----> 3 Qc_added=optimizeur_pyomo(Qc_added,CB)
      4 print(Qc_added)
      5 P_loss,V,P,Q,R,x,N=net_data(Qc_added)

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10232\3850270929.py in optimizeur_pyomo(Qc_added, CB)
     62     model.objective = Objective(expr =b ,sense = minimize )
     63     #solve with mindtPy
---> 64     opt =SolverFactory('mindtpy').solve(model,strategy='OA',time_limit=2000, mip_solver='cplex',
     65                                         mip_solver_mipgap=0.1,regularization_mip_threads = 1,
     66                                         nlp_solver='ipopt',add_regularization='hess_only_lag')

~\anaconda.mars.2023\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\MindtPy.py in solve(self, model, **kwds)
    117         config.set_value(kwds, skip_implicit=True)
    118 
--> 119         return SolverFactory(
    120             _supported_algorithms[config.strategy][0]).solve(model, **kwds)
    121 

~\anaconda.mars.2023\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\algorithm_base_class.py in solve(self, model, **kwds)
   2387             # Algorithm main loop
   2388             with time_code(self.timing, 'main loop'):
-> 2389                 self.MindtPy_iteration_loop(config)
   2390 
   2391             # Load solution

~\anaconda.mars.2023\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\algorithm_base_class.py in MindtPy_iteration_loop(self, config)
   2470             with time_code(self.timing, 'main'):
   2471                 main_mip, main_mip_results = self.solve_main(config)
-> 2472             if self.handle_main_mip_termination(main_mip, main_mip_results):
   2473                 break
   2474             # Call the MILP post-solve callback

~\anaconda.mars.2023\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\algorithm_base_class.py in handle_main_mip_termination(self, main_mip, main_mip_results)
   2439                     should_terminate = True
   2440                 else:
-> 2441                     self.handle_main_other_conditions(
   2442                         main_mip, main_mip_results, self.config)
   2443         else:

~\anaconda.mars.2023\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\algorithm_base_class.py in handle_main_other_conditions(self, main_mip, main_mip_results, config)
   1667                                                          get_main_elapsed_time(self.timing)))
   1668         else:
-> 1669             raise ValueError(
   1670                 'MindtPy unable to handle MILP main termination condition '
   1671                 'of %s. Solver message: %s' %

ValueError: MindtPy unable to handle MILP main termination condition of unknown. Solver message: <undefined>
```